# Updating table based on derived column as well as returning the resultset of the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written a SQL Server stored procedure that returns a derived column in its result set. The derived column returns the difference in days and if the difference is less than 24 hours, then it returns hours.

I need to call an update statement based on value that comes from the derived column (`NoOfDays`) is -1: The storedprocedure would however return the entire resultset that includes the derived column and perform the update if necessary

```
update [org].[User] 
set [Disabled] = 0
where id = @UserID AND ....
```

How do include this update statement to do that in this stored procedure

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE declaration.UserAgreementsOutstanding 
    (@UserID INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE ua 
        SET ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry = GETUTCDATE() + a.ReviewPeriodInDays
        FROM declaration.UserAgreement ua
        INNER JOIN declaration.Agreement a ON ua.AgreementID = a.ID
        WHERE ua.USERID = @UserID 
          AND ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry IS NULL;

        SELECT 
            ua.ID AS UserAgreementID,
            A.ID AS AgreementID,
            A.Code,
            A.ComplianceCode,
            A.Name, A.Description,
            A.Version,
            ua.UserAgreementStateID,
            uas.Name AS UserAgreementStateName,
            ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry,
            declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry) AS NoOfDays,
            A.Data,
            pa.ID AS AuthoredByID,
            pa.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS AuthoredByName,
            A.Authored,
            ia.ID AS IssuedByID,
            ia.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS IssuedByName,
            A.Issued
        FROM
            declaration.Agreement AS A
        INNER JOIN 
            declaration.UserAgreement AS ua ON A.ID = ua.AgreementID
        INNER JOIN 
            declaration.UserAgreementState AS uas ON ua.UserAgreementStateID = uas.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            common.Person AS pa ON A.AuthoredBy = pa.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            common.Person AS ia ON A.IssuedBy = ia.ID
        WHERE 
            ua.UserID = 607
            AND uas.Code IN ('ISS', 'DEF') -- Issued, Deferred
            AND A.Draft = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not a draft.
            AND A.Deleted = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not deleted.
            AND (A.Issued <= GETUTCDATE() OR A.Issued IS NULL)   
            AND (A.Expires > GETUTCDATE() OR A.Expires IS NULL)

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- do some pseudo logging
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION declaration.GetDifferenceInDaysOrHours(@AcceptanceWindowExpiry datetime)  
RETURNS int   
AS   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInDays INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifferenceInHours INT;
    DECLARE @timeDifference INT;

    SELECT @timeDifferenceInDays = DATEDIFF(d,  GETUTCDATE(), @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  

    IF @timeDifferenceInDays > 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifference = @timeDifferenceInDays
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @timeDifferenceInHours = DATEDIFF(HOUR,  GETUTCDATE(),  @AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  

        IF @timeDifferenceInHours >= 0 AND @timeDifferenceInHours <= 24
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @timeDifference = @timeDifferenceInHours
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @timeDifference = -1
        END
    END

    RETURN @timeDifference;  
END;
```

The current resultset

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your update sets the determining value to utc date + some number of **days**, so why would this "reverse" logic return anything other than "some number of days"? TBH, it seems rather a foolish approach to define a value without consistent unit of measure but labelled as "NumberOfDays" - but I don't have to make sense out of it.

Comment: I basically disabling the user if any of the records in the result set contains -1. That’s all what I am intending to do. The stored procedure would return the result set that included the derived field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add UPDATE statement to disable the user before updating the user agreement. Also, have the transaction scope.

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @OutStandingUserAgreements TABLE(UserID INT, AgreementID INT, TimeDifference INT)

INSERT INTO @OutStandingUserAgreements(UserID, AgreementID , TimeDifference)
SELECT U.Id
 , UA.AgreementID
 , declaration.UserAgreementsOutstanding(UA.AcceptanceWindowExpiry) AS TimeDifference
FROM [org].[User] AS U
INNER JOIN  declaration.UserAgreement AS UA
ON      U.UserID = UA.UserID 
where       U.id = @UserID;


-- We are disabling user here, based on the UserAgreement Status
UPDATE      U
SET     U.[Disabled] = 0
FROM        [org].[User] AS U
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
@OutStandingUserAgreements AS oua
WHERE   oua.UserID = U.ID
AND     oua.TimeDifference = -1);


UPDATE ua 
SET ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry = GETUTCDATE() + a.ReviewPeriodInDays
FROM declaration.UserAgreement ua
INNER JOIN declaration.Agreement a ON ua.AgreementID = a.ID
WHERE ua.USERID = @UserID 
  AND ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry IS NULL;


IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Org.User WHERE Id = @UserID AND Disabled = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT -1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 
            ua.ID AS UserAgreementID,
            A.ID AS AgreementID,
            A.Code,
            A.ComplianceCode,
            A.Name, A.Description,
            A.Version,
            ua.UserAgreementStateID,
            uas.Name AS UserAgreementStateName,
            ua.AcceptanceWindowExpiry,
            oua.TimeDifference AS NoOfDays,
            A.Data,
            pa.ID AS AuthoredByID,
            pa.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS AuthoredByName,
            A.Authored,
            ia.ID AS IssuedByID,
            ia.FirstName + ' ' + pa.LastName AS IssuedByName,
            A.Issued
        FROM
            declaration.Agreement AS A
        INNER JOIN 
            declaration.UserAgreement AS ua ON A.ID = ua.AgreementID
        INNER JOIN 
            declaration.UserAgreementState AS uas ON ua.UserAgreementStateID = uas.ID
        INNER JOIN @OutStandingUserAgreements AS oua
             ON oua.AgreementID = ua.AgreementID
        LEFT JOIN 
            common.Person AS pa ON A.AuthoredBy = pa.ID
        LEFT JOIN 
            common.Person AS ia ON A.IssuedBy = ia.ID
        WHERE 
            ua.UserID = 607
            AND uas.Code IN ('ISS', 'DEF') -- Issued, Deferred
            AND A.Draft = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not a draft.
            AND A.Deleted = CONVERT(BIT, 0) -- Not deleted.
            AND (A.Issued <= GETUTCDATE() OR A.Issued IS NULL)   
            AND (A.Expires > GETUTCDATE() OR A.Expires IS NULL)
END 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;


END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH
```

Comment: In your approach i am firing the declaration.UserAgreementsOutstanding(UA.AcceptanceWindowExpiry)  twice. One is for the update and second is in the business logic. select statement. I need to pass the derived value to my client application

Comment: Edited my answer. I have added a table variable and stored the results. I am reusing the table variable subsequently.

Comment: I am getting error on invalid keyword ON in the following statement UPDATE      U
SET     U.[Disabled] = 0
FROM        [org].[User] AS U
WHERE   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM 
@OutStandingUserAgreements AS oua
ON      oua.UserID = U.UserID
AND     oua.TimeDifference = -1);

Comment: Sorry. when I corrected the code, I missed to update ON with WHERE clause. I have updated the code. Please check now.